# Variance of Sample Mean in Time Series

Tags: probability, limits, stochastic-processes, time-series

The following is a proposition which is important for deriving the distribution of the sample mean for a covariance stationary process.

**Proposition:**

Let $\{x_{t}\}$ be a mean zero covariance stationary time series with $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|\gamma_{x}(k)|<\infty$ ( where $\gamma_{x}(k)$ is the autocovariance function at lag $k$).

Then $\frac{1}{T} \mathbb{V} \left[ \sum_{t=1}^{T} x_{t} \right] = \gamma_{x}(0) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\gamma_{x}(k)$

**Proof:**

My proof thus far is:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{T} \mathbb{V} \left[ \sum_{t=1}^{T} x_{t} \right] &= \frac{1}{T}\left[  \sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{V}[x_{t}] +  \mathop{\sum^T\sum^T}_{i\neq j} Cov(x_{i}, x_{j})  \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{T}\left[  \sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{V}[x_{t}] + 2 \mathop{\sum^T\sum^T}_{i < j} Cov(x_{i}, x_{j})  \right]\\
&=  \frac{1}{T}\left[ T\cdot \gamma_{x}(0) + 2 (T-1) \cdot \gamma_{x}(1) + 2(T-2) \cdot \gamma_{x}(2) + \ldots + 4  \gamma_{x}(T-2) + 2 \gamma_{x}(T-1) \right]\\
&=   \frac{1}{T}\left[ T\cdot \gamma_{x}(0) + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{T-1} (T-i) \cdot \gamma_{x}(i)  \right]\\
&=  \gamma_{x}(0) + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{T-1} \frac{(T-i)}{T} \cdot \gamma_{x}(i) \\
\end{align*}
Now all I need to show is:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{T\to\infty}  \gamma_{x}(0) + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{T-1} \frac{(T-i)}{T} \cdot \gamma_{x}(i) = \gamma_{x}(0) + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \gamma_{x}(i) \\
\end{align*}

However I am having trouble with this limit and am worried it does not converge.

**Context:**

This proposition was stated by my professor in a time series class and has been used to prove many other results. However it is possible I have approached the proof in the wrong way. Any input will help.

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154070/where-is-the-dominated-convergence-theorem-being-used/273021#273021

Answer (score 1):

The upper limit of your sum should be $T-1$ (since the $t=T$ term is zero). We can write

$$\sum_{i=1}^{T-1}\frac{T-i}T\gamma_x(i)=\sum_{i=1}^{T-1}\left(1-\frac iT\right)\gamma_x(i):=a_T. $$
Clearly $a_T$ need not converge as $T\to\infty$. However, $a_T$ converges if and only if
$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty \gamma_x(i)<\infty $$
(from my time series notes, a proof of this statement is escaping me at the moment). When that limit exists, your result holds.

Comment: I have incorporated this minor change to the limit of the sum. However, the issue of the convergence of $a_{T}$ is at the crux of the proof; not only must $a_{T}$ converge, but it must converge to the desired limit above. Your comment gives me hope, but the proof of your comment is needed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Well, my notes say that the proof is in this book http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9781118186428

Comment: Actually, elementary computations show that the result holds if and only if $$\frac1T\sum_{i=1}^Ti\gamma(i)\to0,$$ a condition which is *implied* by the convergence of the series $$\sum_{i}\gamma(i).$$

Comment: @Did Can you elaborate on why the convergence of your first series to zero is implied by the convergence of the second series? Even a hint would be helpful!

Comment: Rewrite the first sums in terms of the *rests* $\Gamma(i)=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant i}\gamma(k)$ of the second series, which, by hypothesis, are finite and converge to zero.

Comment: @Did I am still having trouble, as although I know that eventually $\gamma(i)\to 0$ I am worried that if this does not happen fast enough then the sum $\sum_{i} i \gamma(i)$ will diverge.

Comment: The condition that $\frac1T\sum\limits_{i=1}^Ti\gamma(i)\to0$ is strictly weaker than the summability of the series $\sum\limits_ii\gamma(i)$ (since $o(T)$ is weaker than $O(1)$) hence the result may hold even though $\sum\limits_ii\gamma(i)$ diverges.

Comment: To understand why @Did's first comment is valid you should know about [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma).